# How to diagnose EXC_CRASH?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory

A tester sent this crash file:
Not sure what an EXC_CRASH is.

UPDATE:
I can randomly replicate it on device (never in simulator) when rotating my phone. Here is my rotation code:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        imageScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,300); //self.view.bounds;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,300); //self.view.bounds;
    }
    else {
        imageScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460); 
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460); 
    }


    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    if (enableLandscapeOrientation) {
        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) animated:YES];
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Symbolicated Crash Log:

```
Incident Identifier: EC78AFBF-B73D-4490-B7E3-D6A7CDA5D449
CrashReporter Key:   1657e021ecba3a19c5ed9f0cff62947a426a2bc2
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         StockTwits [1565]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/915A215F-EA55-4B98-901B-67E4C856B59E/StockTwits.app/StockTwits
Identifier:      StockTwits
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2010-08-21 16:04:06.293 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0.2 (8A400)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791d0 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791c0 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791b2 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008d6fa abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000059ec _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000048cc objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0009fa70 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0009ef0e ___forwarding___ + 502
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00031678 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
13  UIKit                           0x00148194 -[UISearchDisplayController windowWillAnimateRotation:] + 92
14  Foundation                      0x00018fb0 _nsnote_callback + 136
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00069e6c __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0001a374 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
17  Foundation                      0x000040bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
18  UIKit                           0x000ed5d0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:duration:force:] + 3108
19  UIKit                           0x000eee6c -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 44
20  UIKit                           0x0007763c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 68
21  UIKit                           0x000775b6 -[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation:] + 106
22  UIKit                           0x00077506 -[UIWindow _handleDeviceOrientationChange:] + 82
23  Foundation                      0x00018fb0 _nsnote_callback + 136
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00069e6c __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0001a374 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
26  Foundation                      0x000040bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
27  UIKit                           0x00040582 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 138
28  UIKit                           0x0005d670 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2732
29  UIKit                           0x0005ca56 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
30  UIKit                           0x0005c500 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5016
31  GraphicsServices                0x00004140 PurpleEventCallback + 660
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00071aa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00073848 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00074626 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
37  GraphicsServices                0x000036e8 GSEventRunModal + 108
38  GraphicsServices                0x00003794 GSEventRun + 56
39  UIKit                           0x000062a0 -[UIApplication _run] + 396
40  UIKit                           0x00004e10 UIApplicationMain + 664
41  StockTwits                      0x00002d58 0x1000 + 7512
42  StockTwits                      0x00002d28 0x1000 + 7464

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002dc4c kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6e44 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6894 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6a34 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007ad82 _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073fcc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001658 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003724 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000722c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00074582 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x00003056 RunWebThread(void*) + 362
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a986 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000700e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001658 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003724 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000722c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00074582 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x0003b71e +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x0000bc96 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x000909da __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a986 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x000700e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00025a20 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00077e70 __CFSocketManager + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a986 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000700e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007b85c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007ae98 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073fcc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e90724c
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x09ad4aec      r6: 0x2fffda84      r7: 0x2fffda94
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x088ca2d0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffda94      lr: 0x352741c7      pc: 0x352741d0
  cpsr: 0x080f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x40fff +StockTwits armv7  <7316bae7933ce5f735f322059a3c72db> /var/mobile/Applications/915A215F-EA55-4B98-901B-67E4C856B59E/StockTwits.app/StockTwits
  0x5ee000 -   0x5effff  dns.so armv7  <240b8d3f07b4fcb234de598f8e67de1a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv7  <193570c1391880df7da870149117e49e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30095000 - 0x300b4fff  MobileSync armv7  <be1b235840ae625d49f684c39ab083da> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x30135000 - 0x30686fff  WebCore armv7  <859bdd351085819fb4da07d12b41543f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30707000 - 0x30715fff  Notes armv7  <56a4dfe587cf5b965edbd6c390ccbf24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x30ac5000 - 0x30adafff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <1ed920d5a995cd94e71c41631d7c551e> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30adc000 - 0x30bc4fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <9bcf5fe3e7abc344425e581ff2896579> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x30bc5000 - 0x30bfffff  IMAVCore armv7  <2bd608c3f68c2e9cd73212007eaf248d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x30ca5000 - 0x30d4bfff  WebKit armv7  <a1d04572b3214188f60f2d1961ac1fe8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x30eb4000 - 0x30f76fff  CFNetwork armv7  <9fdd61632fd1b48d65daba561528946f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x30f77000 - 0x30f7ffff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <0bd0c65f4350b5d81f81449fae029a04> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x30f80000 - 0x31007fff  Message armv7  <32383927596c6b8c0837a5cd4b2bc0d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x31014000 - 0x310a3fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <7748fd02215f7d77eae9191cba201b97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x310a5000 - 0x310a7fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c668de69901cce316252204135b4ce7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x310a8000 - 0x3113ffff  MediaPlayer armv7  <2c4b66a2002c1b3222f70c71d8844455> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31140000 - 0x31193fff  EventKit armv7  <7f18bef514a44edeccc9619b10f4f1c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x31297000 - 0x3129cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <d33678689445fcf1898314262fd1ebd3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3129f000 - 0x312e7fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <3b4a2849c10d100a178a3c2d9f6af523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x312e8000 - 0x312e9fff  DataMigration armv7  <2a90bcfdd519f8d7d3487151c77443ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x312ea000 - 0x31358fff  ProofReader armv7  <479bd40ac65cb7e6c3000d79d649571f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31359000 - 0x3142bfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <17c9c36ae8824496b507446869cd4d9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31454000 - 0x31457fff  CertUI armv7  <fff763f01a1037dcd9ce6914e25068ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x31472000 - 0x314a0fff  AppSupport armv7  <2a64271b39599b2180d0dfd3141027ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31663000 - 0x3280dfff  UIKit armv7  <6c767127e477e6ac7b7f083857ca8064> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32824000 - 0x32868fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <36b9bc7d02e29c8d321dd0d7bf7e115e> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3286b000 - 0x3286dfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1fdf9182a63464743901526caf39240a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3286e000 - 0x3287efff  TelephonyUI armv7  <dd37e6ff7158a0d44c99efa6ad659dd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x329b6000 - 0x329ccfff  RawCamera armv7  <78168f60a21e67ce307c5ce30054dba6> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x329dc000 - 0x329e2fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <df3c6cea5e6848109a6e033e1d883320> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x329e3000 - 0x329ebfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <b8fc1381e87a55740d9ac66195039a63> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x329f0000 - 0x329fbfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <7194df9e594ae0fd9d9c600ccf456a08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x329fc000 - 0x32a46fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <baab09769f92decea73680bc15aa8618> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32a83000 - 0x32a8cfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <3b3f590d3bd1fdf29a14769cbe8dc933> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x32aa3000 - 0x32ad2fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <4c4faee61a6e7d80d6d3a58194075642> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32ad3000 - 0x32ad5fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <06dd6032c40b1feb094d63eeb2002d6d> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x32ad6000 - 0x32b16fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <94f3f69708e8f008b3f092430f46e4b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32b17000 - 0x32b59fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bc8796c8e011fea9923170d3c948a694> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32b98000 - 0x32b9bfff  IOSurface armv7  <e67242f81fd1c0fa5e84b3fae5d310ae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32ba6000 - 0x32bb5fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <575a1afc08ed55608075204df14cc5f5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32bb6000 - 0x32bb6fff  vecLib armv7  <85f89752df7814c1b243c26f59388523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32bbf000 - 0x32bc2fff  ApplePushService armv7  <0477bf826cbba75183069e1e80879a99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x32d49000 - 0x32de7fff  Celestial armv7  <7a01b8d8cd2054d9b0d987bda6c52d9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x32de8000 - 0x32f06fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <4022bbf12f11dd1f6b75662c764e7f7c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32f20000 - 0x32f2dfff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <8f6e03c382591e1f30f06e97b4b31570> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x3302b000 - 0x330cbfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <89553a61e05078fd178ac0ea2081ae40> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x330cc000 - 0x331cffff  CoreData armv7  <0abaeddf54d093fa5cf680b0d644d8e9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3325a000 - 0x33379fff  Foundation armv7  <c985a61696030b4d1bdc8fe010f4e43b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3343e000 - 0x3344efff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e63c6e2198f5542561ba108f4458c17d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3344f000 - 0x33489fff  IOKit armv7  <5e0169de165c2fd25a2ddac1f3e19d06> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3348a000 - 0x334b3fff  ContentIndex armv7  <40405e868ddfb485115719c167925b6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x33543000 - 0x33640fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <c88e817481930fa7717688561b70c7f0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x33641000 - 0x33680fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b96f5e231a3e39677b5e3621d61d2f11> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33681000 - 0x33683fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <74e2bd725da63513053b4fa41d8cd89c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33684000 - 0x3368dfff  ITSync armv7  <e00a78c04f8ae7515da25fdc09281f4f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x3368e000 - 0x3371bfff  ImageIO armv7  <abf07fc0430aaf2a2823753c78061aac> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3371c000 - 0x3374afff  MIME armv7  <a6dbab95d27cf0fe94c2251df2549e10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x33772000 - 0x337a5fff  iCalendar armv7  <a8def1c4ef73199eee71bc525005831b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x33810000 - 0x33815fff  BluetoothManager armv7  <c3a48ff43d836b3025597f4ff5e5c858> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x33850000 - 0x33969fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <c4f4fd74dfa672fb4d84914585bbada5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x339da000 - 0x339e0fff  WebUI armv7  <d110132cf1dfaf19ddf0be143d1da277> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebUI.framework/WebUI
0x339e4000 - 0x33ac5fff  GameKitServices armv7  <5bfca52ad46cbf5f8ea3888f646f3511> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
0x33ad1000 - 0x33bf3fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <dea2c74c8c31430c58301edbe2b6eeb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33c21000 - 0x33c6afff  GMM armv7  <9c4efdff49ea9e6a17b5d44bcd98b6c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x33c6f000 - 0x33c87fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <436e3b257ba088ca6f773961ce619892> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33c88000 - 0x33c8bfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <12f82e44ff36b29f8d0661878be83554> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33c8c000 - 0x33c8ffff  ArtworkCache armv7  <8ff796d092ff1a8289611912506bbe44> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x33c90000 - 0x33c9cfff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <bc6bff5b67aae8b97a8cdd43ed7b0bb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x33c9d000 - 0x33ccefff  CoreLocation armv7  <722c5983f0589013d0243e2512d0dd1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x33e36000 - 0x33edefff  QuartzCore armv7  <109b4f6a3d2ee5aa1bb5775ab5a489bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33ee2000 - 0x33f8bfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1d74fa3a5cec309857503a51cb2df667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x33f98000 - 0x33fd9fff  MessageUI armv7  <01029a352fe073ddf5103bad8274f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33fda000 - 0x34004fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <25fba468c726d1a59aa109a5a76631f5> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x34005000 - 0x34034fff  QuickLook armv7  <78442b5e66e7845f89afcc02b6982ef2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x34035000 - 0x342cffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <fbc3f7ad1260a159d75be53218fa9e0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x343a8000 - 0x343b1fff  CoreVideo armv7  <58180e899ec56cd8bca00221dea2bc32> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x343b2000 - 0x343b6fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <942a91e5920a8798c1a1cf75f0750b2f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x343ee000 - 0x3442cfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <cc8d6be7a5021266e26ebd05e9579852> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3442d000 - 0x34435fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <4ec35c4d1e1e73416aea84537829ce91> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x34438000 - 0x34445fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e397de408a0a789f816bc1803ae58faf> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x344e8000 - 0x34521fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d38c937ae3548777da263d2657536189> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3456c000 - 0x3459bfff  CoreText armv7  <76eb1b63d684c3d21dba9e8129666d2f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3459c000 - 0x345d2fff  Security armv7  <7cea1027f1a381b8d6c5ffae4dae0d22> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x345d3000 - 0x34636fff  AVFoundation armv7  <39ad1d85ae4627ed77de7751e8a3b4ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3473c000 - 0x347dbfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <894df23ebbc4df713d9519141a61dd19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x347dc000 - 0x347ddfff  CoreSurface armv7  <042e433142b7faa4c96b23e555faaf13> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3483a000 - 0x34843fff  AccountSettings armv7  <cd5665c4a135694944eca0870d5350c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34844000 - 0x3484bfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5d079712f5a39708647292bccbd4c4e0> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3487c000 - 0x348aafff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <2b44ac2fc47fc45c4006d08019688dbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x348ac000 - 0x348b7fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <19a78978d5908bedc6496470fe542936> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x348e9000 - 0x34929fff  CoreAudio armv7  <1723726845b73efbeca75b33d75f335a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34936000 - 0x3493dfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <6d417a70ec3abd8258ed0fbab0994518> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3493e000 - 0x3496cfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <475259824770c6ff1b63f30238b3ea81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3496d000 - 0x349a3fff  TextInput armv7  <949f29588014140b606042685de1dee6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x349a4000 - 0x349c3fff  Bom armv7  <c73b68b11b2801cefbfbdb6328a7fcfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34a2d000 - 0x34c6bfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <83f1b1c1956ed14bf6f6c7923ee9f2fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x34cb8000 - 0x34ccefff  EAP8021X armv7  <4177ec92cd0e2a4a23c79fac68de5c2e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x34dc3000 - 0x34dd4fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <5e827d18f317b5ce7c61c91656ebc88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34dd5000 - 0x34e07fff  AddressBook armv7  <3dde743216bbf016019b59f821dda6e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34e0d000 - 0x34e0efff  Marco armv7  <89d4f32ac1cbb0b4f5066308fa5f422a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x34e0f000 - 0x34e12fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <85f01f53a7455a34fbdedc76bd692d74> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x34f43000 - 0x34f4ffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <7624f0a9e197261f2df43edb86ba0256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x34f50000 - 0x34f5dfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <27ad6b3a74ce1068586eabd6a553183f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34f5e000 - 0x34f64fff  IAP armv7  <42a87fc47e059f5a73dcff2227b9e0be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x34f67000 - 0x34f7afff  libmis.dylib armv7  <9fbf2930731e2da9863eacdff8b121a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34f7d000 - 0x34fa6fff  IMFoundation armv7  <8e003a136638c28edc7b5333b8166b5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x34fa7000 - 0x34fecfff  IMCore armv7  <d5045ad82f9b89b1d4992f1f500724fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x34fed000 - 0x3500cfff  Conference armv7  <f38c0563d62880f21ee676529aeafa47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Conference.framework/Conference
0x3502d000 - 0x35151fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <802e4d5c449b69d9552809e5230baa84> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35152000 - 0x35155fff  ActorKit armv7  <9858fda6756fb624164b7b83aefa6701> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x35156000 - 0x35156fff  Accelerate armv7  <f4c04cdfdb64d209828315cdd5b60bf9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3518f000 - 0x351c9fff  CoreMedia armv7  <6df383495d1acd2b036ad674a29d75c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x351d0000 - 0x351fafff  DataAccess armv7  <190e9fd23dcbf029e5a8cdb9fb56befc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x351fb000 - 0x35308fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <3fcf32f3ad8ef745480b5b36efc41953> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Not exactly sure where UISearchDisplayController is coming from. I have a ViewController that that has a UISearchDisplayController, which pushes another ViewController onto the stack, which doesn't have a UISearchDisplayController...

Comment: I believe EXC_CRASH is from abort() or terminate(), as evidenced by "SIGABRT". From the stack trace, it looks like it might be an unhandled exception. It's not easy to go get symbols without the rest of the crash report (in particular, the "Binary Images:" section).

Comment: updated with full crash log...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EXC_CRASH is a mach exception that just means the application terminated abnormally. The parenthetical is the signal that caused the exception, in your case it's SIGABRT which almost always means that you have an un-handled exception somewhere or you have some code that is calling `abort()` for some reason (again, generally the un-handled exception handler calls this in the end).

You have to symbolicate your crash log with the symbols file that you created for this specific release (the DSYM file that was in the build directory where your app file was). That will at least tell you exactly which line in your code triggered the final abort.

Based on just the libraries here, I'm going to guess that you have an over-released object that you are messaging at some point. Try running the static analyzer to see if it finds any memory problems and symbolicate the crash log so you can at least get a starting point.

This could also be coming from a failed assertion, like index out of bounds or what have you, but since it's so far down in the view hierarchy, my guess is bad memory (the wrong object at the current memory location).

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log