# iPhone - no sense after symbolicating a crash file

Tags: iphone, xcode, symbolicate

Apple have sent me a crash log from an app sent for approval. Despite not crashing in all my tests in 3 devices, they say it is crashing on launch. After symbolicating the file, I get this.

Looking at this and means nothing to me. I don't see where the error is. I know it crashed on thread 0, but which line?

Any clues? Thanks.

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         myApplication [11197]
Identifier:      myApplication
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-06-08 17:21:12.760 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.1 (8G4)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35407a1c 0x353f6000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3305f3b4 0x3302c000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33057bf8 0x3302c000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34c8fa64 0x34c4b000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x307e006c 0x307da000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34c8de36 0x34c4b000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34c8de8a 0x34c4b000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34c8df5a 0x34c4b000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x307dec84 0x307da000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3613b1b8 0x36099000 + 663992
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3613a642 0x36099000 + 661058
11  CoreFoundation                  0x360b1178 0x36099000 + 98680
12  myApplication                       0x000bad78 0xb3000 + 32120
13  myApplication                       0x000bb070 0xb3000 + 32880
14  myApplication                       0x000bb16c 0xb3000 + 33132
15  UIKit                           0x35ed556e 0x35cda000 + 2078062
16  PhotoLibrary                    0x3370be90 0x336c8000 + 278160
17  PhotoLibrary                    0x3370a852 0x336c8000 + 272466
18  PhotoLibrary                    0x33724338 0x336c8000 + 377656
19  PhotoLibrary                    0x33724094 0x336c8000 + 376980
20  Foundation                      0x34a8d17c 0x34a7f000 + 57724
21  CoreFoundation                  0x36106208 0x36099000 + 446984
22  CoreFoundation                  0x360a0ee4 0x36099000 + 32484
23  Foundation                      0x34a8a5cc 0x34a7f000 + 46540
24  Celestial                       0x34e33072 0x34e29000 + 41074
25  Celestial                       0x34e54a0a 0x34e29000 + 178698
26  CoreFoundation                  0x361059a8 0x36099000 + 444840
27  CoreFoundation                  0x36106208 0x36099000 + 446984
28  CoreFoundation                  0x360a0ee4 0x36099000 + 32484
29  CoreFoundation                  0x360ac42e 0x36099000 + 78894
30  CoreMedia                       0x30db4e68 0x30da0000 + 85608
31  MediaToolbox                    0x3685c830 0x3679c000 + 788528
32  MediaToolbox                    0x3686011e 0x3679c000 + 803102
33  MediaToolbox                    0x3686009c 0x3679c000 + 802972
34  MediaToolbox                    0x3685fffe 0x3679c000 + 802814
35  CoreFoundation                  0x36103bd8 0x36099000 + 437208
36  CoreFoundation                  0x3610ea90 0x36099000 + 481936
37  CoreFoundation                  0x36110838 0x36099000 + 489528
38  CoreFoundation                  0x36111606 0x36099000 + 493062
39  CoreFoundation                  0x360a1ebc 0x36099000 + 36540
40  CoreFoundation                  0x360a1dc4 0x36099000 + 36292
41  GraphicsServices                0x35ac1418 0x35abd000 + 17432
42  GraphicsServices                0x35ac14c4 0x35abd000 + 17604
43  UIKit                           0x35d08d62 0x35cda000 + 191842
44  UIKit                           0x35d06800 0x35cda000 + 182272
45  myApplication                       0x000b4c9a 0xb3000 + 7322
46  myApplication                       0x000b4c64 0xb3000 + 7268

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
  r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
  r4: 0x3ecdf48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x1eda0afc      r7: 0x2feb029c
  r8: 0x1ed58c90    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x1edefec0     r11: 0x00000000
  ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2feb0290      lr: 0x3305f3bb      pc: 0x35407a1c
cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
 0xb3000 -    0xcdfff +myApplication armv7   /var/mobile/Applications/57BDE03E-561E-4BA8-8D68-4E037FC2E54F/myApplication.app/myApplication
0x2feb2000 - 0x2fed7fff  dyld armv7   /usr/lib/dyld
0x30776000 - 0x30777fff  MP4VH2.videodecoder armv7   /System/Library/VideoDecoders/MP4VH2.videodecoder
0x30778000 - 0x30781fff  CoreVideo armv7   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
```

Comment: You did the symbolicating part wrong. Really wrong.

Comment: Yeah, it's not symbolicated yet. If you did a Build & Archive and haven't deleted the resulting dSYMs yet then you should be able to symbolicate. If the Organizer won't symbolicate then it's likely you wiped the dSYMs at some point (including performing a Build & Archive since the one you sent off without a version change).

Comment: so I don't know what else I can do. I have dragged the files to device logs on organizer, I have the dSYM files, I see the message "symbolicating..." and then this is what it shows me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Xcode 4, there's a known issue with it not symbolicating crash logs correctly. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log/5491334) for a workaround.

Comment: that's it. I used the solution from this other question and it is now symbolicating correctly. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can let Xcode do the symbolification for you if you are unsure of how to do it. Just drag it into the Xcode Organizer. If Xcode is unable to do it, you will not be able to do it unless you saved your dSYM's in a place that is not visible by spotlight.