# How can I symbolicate from a .crash file in XCode4 that I've downloaded from iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, xcode4, app-store-connect, crash-reports, symbolicate

There is a similar question about symbolicating a .crash file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports).  However this question does not cover how to easily symbolicate in Xcode 4.

I have downloaded the .crash files from iTunes connect.  All my production versions have been archived in Xcode.  When I then go to Devices>Device Logs and try to import the .crash file, nothing happens.  The list of crashes does not increase at all.

To add, I have been submitting my apps by archiving first.  It appears that there isn't the same build folder that there used to be in older Xcode versions.  Now the build folder appears to be empty in apps built with Xcode4. It looks like the builds are now in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{application-named-folder}/Build/Products/{debug/release folder}

According to [this top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports), in prior versions it sounds like this was all you had to do to symbolicate your crash report.  Is there something new in XCode4?  I have looked around quite a bit and tried a number of things and can't seem to get this dang .crash file to import into Organizer.

Comment: duplicate question [Xcode 4 failure to symbolicate Crash Log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log)

Comment: huh, i never saw that post in all my queries.  You must have used a term I hadn't.  I went through that question though, and it still does not seem to fix the issue.  Shouldn't it be as easy as dragging the .crash report into Organizer, or am I totally missing something?

Comment: Did you take a look at the blog http://www.goosoftware.co.uk/blog/the-symbolicator-helps-those-who-help-themselves/

Comment: Yes, after you shared that link I did.  However, my problem isn't that it isn't symbolicating correctly.  The .crash file isn't even showing up at all in the list.  Having at least the memory locations would be a start, but it just kind works for a few seconds, then nothing.

Comment: Did you try to run the command **symbolicatecrash** from Terminal prompt?

Comment: I did not as I don't know where the .dSYM file goes in Xcode4 builds.  The builds folder is now empty, however there are .xcarchive files now of the production builds.  I just am not sure what the solution is for Xcode4 and have not found a good description of a solution.

Comment: You might know where it is, but Xcode doesn't. If you read all the answer to the duplicate question I linked to earlier, you would have reach http://factotum.me/blog/2011/04/cant-symbolicate-xcode4-archive-builds/  or rdar://problem/9241304 or [dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/404524#404524)  It's broken.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Answer (score -1):

That is good [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546766/1180406). It work for all .crash files what I seen. Another solution do not help.

Comment: Don't just link other people's answers as an answer of your own. This should be a comment on the OPs question.