# Xcode 4 fails to symbolicate debug builds

Tags: ios4, xcode4, symbolicate

It is my understanding that Xcode should be able to automatically symbolicate **debug** builds so that I don't need to "build and archive" to preserve the .dSYM files. Is this correct? What could be the reason if it doesn't work?
Everything in the crashlog has a proper description except from my own calls:

```
9   CoreData     0x340dd340 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 184
10  TodayDev     0x0000b670 0x1000 + 42608
11  TodayDev     0x00005922 0x1000 + 18722
12  UIKit        0x359f061e -[UIApplication significantTimeChange] + 38
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log) and excluded the mentioned directories from Spotlight. Still no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [patched version of symbolicatecrash](https://github.com/chrispix/symbolicatecrash-fix), which should work for debug builds too, as long as you haven't deleted the build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that my friend who is working on the same app doesn't have this problem and he uses the same tools/versions. I guess it is not related to the symbolicatecrash script since it works for him with debug builds.