# Symbolicate XCode4 crash reports

Tags: xcode4, symbolicate, symbolicatecrash

I'm trying to get XCode 4 to symbolicate a crash report. I've googled and followed this link (https://github.com/chrispix/symbolicatecrash-fix) but get stopped.  The instructions say "To fix your iOS crash report symbolication, move /usr/local/bin/symbolicatecrash aside and copy in the version in this repo."  Well, I cannot find "/usr/local/bin/" on my Mac.  I'm new to the Mac world, so I'm sure there's something I'm not understanding.  If "/usr/local/bin/" doesn't exist, then where is XCode 4 finding symbolicatecrash?  Please point a newbie in the right direction as I have a lot of bugs to be fixing.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Answer (score 10, accepted):

that tool has been relocated to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash in newer version of the SDK

you would run it as:

> ./symbolicatecrash -A -v [crashlog-filename] MyApp.dSYM

keep in mind this is for iOS only, for OSX see http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html (for the app to contain the symbols "DWARF with dSYM" must be enabled in it's build settings)

you would run it as:

> ./symbolizecrashlog [application-name] [crashlog-filename] > symbolized.crash

I would like to add that all this usually is done automatically, these manual approaches are for cases when there are issues with the system symbols database as discussed in [Xcode 4 failure to symbolicate Crash Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log)

Comment: Apple moved/killed the page as they do, it was titled "Debugging and Symbolizing Crash Dumps in Xcode" if anyone manages to find it, not even the google cache at http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html has it

Comment: I found a working link with similar information at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html#SECNOSYMBOLS