# what could be causing the crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have app, which is crashing in some devices. I test the app in simulation and my iPhone 4S and iPad 2 with different iOS. It doesn't have any problem.

Finally I got a .crash file. Now I have the following .crash file but I don't know how can I find the bug. Also I have Archive file too.

```
Incident Identifier: FAA5BAF1-.....
CrashReporter Key:   b385d67d0f4.....
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         myApp [1262]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/094A6965-AA00-421E-A3CE-98CF2F275362/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:      myApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-05
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x37c7888f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32fa9259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37bca9e9 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 129
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37bcce79 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 45
4   myApp                           0x000198f5 0x1000 + 100597
5   myApp                           0x0000620b 0x1000 + 21003
6   myApp                           0x000058e1 0x1000 + 18657
7   UIKit                           0x30a8ac8b -[UIViewController view] + 167
8   UIKit                           0x30a971e9 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 25
9   UIKit                           0x30a97059 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 37
10  UIKit                           0x30a96f3f -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 35
11  UIKit                           0x30a967c1 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 501
12  UIKit                           0x30a96503 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 251
13  UIKit                           0x30a963c3 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 179
14  UIKit                           0x30a54f15 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 149
15  CoreFoundation                  0x37bd71fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
```

---

**UPDATE**

Regarding to your comments to "symbolicatecrash" the .crash file, the result was the following:

```
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore, base address 30e5d000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, base address 32e50000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib, base address 34450000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore, base address 32f17000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib, base address 30778000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Desktop/myApp.app/myApp, base address 1000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices, base address 35f5d000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation, base address 37a6f000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib, base address 3719d000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, base address 308fe000
got symbolicator for /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib, base address 32ccd000
Incident Identifier: FAA5BAF1-....
CrashReporter Key:   b385d67....
Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
Process:         myApp [1262]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/094A6965-AA00-421E-A3CE-98CF2F275362/myApp.app/myApp
Identifier:      myApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-05 01:46:59.281 +0430
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x37c7888f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32fa9259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37bca9e9 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 129
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37bcce79 +[NSArray arrayWithObject:] + 45
4   myApp                           0x000198f5 -[FirstViewController fetchEventsForThisMonth::] (FirstViewController.m:4524)
5   myApp                           0x0000620b -[FirstViewController matrixGenerator] (FirstViewController.m:1255)
6   myApp                           0x000058e1 -[FirstViewController viewDidLoad] (FirstViewController.m:1084)
7   UIKit                           0x30a8ac8b -[UIViewController view] + 167
8   UIKit                           0x30a971e9 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 25
9   UIKit                           0x30a97059 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 37
10  UIKit                           0x30a96f3f -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 35
11  UIKit                           0x30a967c1 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 501
12  UIKit                           0x30a96503 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 251
13  UIKit                           0x30a963c3 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 179
14  UIKit                           0x30a54f15 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 149
15  CoreFoundation                  0x37bd71fb -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 43
16  QuartzCore                      0x3306caa5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 217
17  QuartzCore                      0x3306c6bd CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 217
18  QuartzCore                      0x33070843 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 227
19  QuartzCore                      0x3307057f CA::Transaction::commit() + 315
20  QuartzCore                      0x33098911 CA::Transaction::flush() + 45
21  QuartzCore                      0x330988e3 +[CATransaction flush] + 35
22  UIKit                           0x30a5ffb1 _afterCACommitHandler + 53
23  CoreFoundation                  0x37c4cb1b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
24  CoreFoundation                  0x37c4ad57 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 259
25  CoreFoundation                  0x37c4b0b1 __CFRunLoopRun + 761
26  CoreFoundation                  0x37bce4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
27  CoreFoundation                  0x37bce36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
28  GraphicsServices                0x360b1439 GSEventRunModal + 137
29  UIKit                           0x30a7fcd5 UIApplicationMain + 1081
30  myApp                           0x000028fb main (main.m:13)
31  myApp                           0x000028b4 0x1000 + 6324


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x308d932c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e6a208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e63298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x372f3f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x372f1346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32fa9350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x372f13be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x372f144a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x372f281e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32fa92a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x37bce506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x37bce366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x360b1432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x30a7fcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  myApp                           0x000028f4 main (main.m:13)
15  myApp                           0x000028ac 0x1000 + 6316

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x308c93a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x345a3f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x345a3c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x308c9004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x308c91fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37c4c3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37c4b124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37bce49e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37bce366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x31056c9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e2b72e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e2b5e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x308d9cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e25f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32e25cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3e7a5d98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdffa48
    r8: 0x01044600    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00472830     r11: 0x000431fc
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffa3c      lr: 0x32e6a20f      pc: 0x308d932c
  cpsr: 0x00010010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x3afff +myApp armv7  <feef5c2f58ac34c09926a37b8c1ae2dd> /var/mobile/Applications/094A6965-AA00-421E-A3CE-98CF2F275362/myApp.app/myApp
0x2fe41000 - 0x2fe62fff  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30157000 - 0x30157fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30229000 - 0x30301fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30332000 - 0x3033cfff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x303b4000 - 0x30411fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x30412000 - 0x306d3fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x306e5000 - 0x306edfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x306f0000 - 0x30715fff  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x30762000 - 0x30762fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x308c8000 - 0x308defff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x30924000 - 0x30935fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30936000 - 0x309e3fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x309e4000 - 0x309fafff  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30a4e000 - 0x30ef0fff  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x30f6e000 - 0x30fa9fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x30fad000 - 0x3176cfff  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x317d1000 - 0x3191afff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x31ad6000 - 0x31b27fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x31c72000 - 0x31c77fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31c78000 - 0x31e1efff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31ebf000 - 0x31ec2fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x31ec3000 - 0x31f08fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x31f10000 - 0x31f1cfff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x31f1f000 - 0x31f54fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x31fdf000 - 0x31fdffff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x31fe0000 - 0x31ffffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3225e000 - 0x3225ffff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x32260000 - 0x32263fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x323e4000 - 0x3241cfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32863000 - 0x328a2fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x328e1000 - 0x32924fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x32ad2000 - 0x32ae3fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x32b7f000 - 0x32b83fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x32b87000 - 0x32bc3fff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x32ce2000 - 0x32ceefff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x32cfc000 - 0x32cfffff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x32d09000 - 0x32da2fff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x32da3000 - 0x32e1cfff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x32e1d000 - 0x32ea9fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32eaa000 - 0x32eabfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x32f11000 - 0x32f15fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32fa0000 - 0x33066fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33067000 - 0x33158fff  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33159000 - 0x3315ffff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33330000 - 0x3335cfff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3337e000 - 0x33382fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x333c7000 - 0x3342afff  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x3342b000 - 0x33434fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x33454000 - 0x3349efff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x33516000 - 0x3351cfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x33521000 - 0x336defff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x337e0000 - 0x337f9fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33caa000 - 0x33d02fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33dd0000 - 0x33ddffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33e03000 - 0x33e05fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x33e94000 - 0x33ed0fff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3426d000 - 0x34451fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3445b000 - 0x34549fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3454d000 - 0x34561fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x345a0000 - 0x345b6fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x345b7000 - 0x345bbfff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x346cd000 - 0x346cefff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x34a05000 - 0x34a25fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x34a26000 - 0x34ad4fff  EventKitUI armv7  <bfcf0e8e0f1836619e6d43ca2b0b3230> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKitUI.framework/EventKitUI
0x34b3c000 - 0x34bbbfff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34bea000 - 0x34beefff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34c9e000 - 0x34cbbfff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x34e1f000 - 0x34e22fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x34e91000 - 0x34e91fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x34eb0000 - 0x34eeefff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x34eef000 - 0x34eeffff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x350e8000 - 0x3518efff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x35772000 - 0x35778fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x35779000 - 0x357b0fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x35821000 - 0x35844fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x35845000 - 0x35869fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x3586a000 - 0x358b2fff  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x358b3000 - 0x358fffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x35900000 - 0x35904fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x35908000 - 0x3590cfff  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35943000 - 0x35945fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x35946000 - 0x35949fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35963000 - 0x359a0fff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x35b27000 - 0x35b70fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35b74000 - 0x35b7ffff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35c69000 - 0x35ca9fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x35e5c000 - 0x35f33fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3609b000 - 0x360a5fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x360a6000 - 0x360acfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x360ad000 - 0x360b7fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x360b8000 - 0x360c0fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x360c1000 - 0x360d0fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x360d1000 - 0x361f6fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3622b000 - 0x3676ffff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x36775000 - 0x36775fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36776000 - 0x3678cfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x36b4f000 - 0x36b50fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36b51000 - 0x36bc1fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x36c07000 - 0x36c0cfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x36c2e000 - 0x36c2ffff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36c30000 - 0x36c31fff  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x36d07000 - 0x36d0dfff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x36d19000 - 0x36d1dfff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x36d1e000 - 0x36d67fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x36d96000 - 0x36de7fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x36df9000 - 0x36f77fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x36f78000 - 0x36f8dfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x371d7000 - 0x37281fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3728e000 - 0x3728ffff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x372d6000 - 0x372ecfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x372ed000 - 0x372f4fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x373d3000 - 0x3741dfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3741e000 - 0x37421fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x37446000 - 0x37446fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x37447000 - 0x37454fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x37457000 - 0x37527fff  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3752b000 - 0x37567fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x37568000 - 0x3756ffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3758d000 - 0x37592fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x379ea000 - 0x37b2ffff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x37b30000 - 0x37b3cfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37bbf000 - 0x37cd6fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x37cf6000 - 0x37d44fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x37d6a000 - 0x37d79fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x37d7a000 - 0x37dbefff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
```

Comment: You should symbolicate the crash log so that you can know what methods are being called in "myApp". Right now it only gives the memory addresses and offsets for them

Comment: You can symbolicate the crash log using the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248132/symbolicate-xcode4-crash-reports

Comment: Are you using animations to go from one view to another? The crash log seems to something about transitioning between views. How did you get the crash file? Were you able to reproduce it yourself?

Comment: Test it in all iOS versions. I mean from 4.0 to 5.1 iOS. Then you will come to know the answer of your question.

Comment: The for your replies. I done symbolicate and now I post it the update result.

Answer (score 1):

The interesting lines are :

```
4   myApp                           0x000198f5 0x1000 + 100597
5   myApp                           0x0000620b 0x1000 + 21003
6   myApp                           0x000058e1 0x1000 + 18657
```

But your crash report file is not symbolicated.

To do so, go to your Organizer, in "Archive", click on your app and select the archive which has generated the .crash file. If you right click then "Show in finder", it will show a .xarchive. Open the paquet and find the .app file.

Then go in your Terminal, and execute the commands :

```
atos -arch armv7 -o 'pathOfYourAppFile.app'/'nameOfYourApp' 0x000198f5
atos -arch armv7 -o 'pathOfYourAppFile.app'/'nameOfYourApp' 0x0000620b
atos -arch armv7 -o 'pathOfYourAppFile.app'/'nameOfYourApp' 0x000058e1
```

The memory places correspond to the lines 4, 5 & 6 of your crash report. The commands would give you the function where your app crashed.

Hope that helps.

PS : if you did not archive your app, you have to find the .app installed on the crashed device, but it must be the exact one that have generated the crash report, otherwise the memory slot association would be wrong (and it will give you some random functions!).

Comment: Thanks for your try. I tried: atos -arch armv7 -o '/Users/my/Desktop/myApp.app'/'myApp' 0x000198f5atos the result was atos cannot load symbols for the file /Users/my/Desktop/myApp.app/myApp for architecture armv7.

Comment: your memory slot is "0x000198f5atos": is it an error from your comment, or from your command ?

Comment: I tried this: atos -arch armv7 -o '/Users/my/Desktop/myApp.app'/'myApp' 0x000198f5

Answer (score 0):

As David said above, you should symbolicate the crashlog so that you know where your bug occurs.  Aside from *where* it is, the most common cause of this crash is that you passed a nil value to `-arrayWithObject:`.

Comment: Thanks, I did symbolicate and now I post it the update result. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

in the crash report i've seen this...

Hardware Model:      iPad3,1
....
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)

it's an apple crash report issue or the user is using a jailbreacked iOS?