# How to identify the bug from iPhone Crash log

Tags: ios, crash-reports, ios5.1

I am using TestFlight SDK.  I got the crash log from a user and I cant reproduce the issue.  I like to know how to identify the bug location from crash log.  Any help is greatly appreciated..  Thanks in advance.

I have masked my project name from the log.

Sorry if my question is so basic.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret keyword is `symbolicate a crash` ;)

Here is a blog post on it: http://blog.testflightapp.com/post/11322114068/real-time-symbolication

Answer (score 1):

You have to symbolicate your crash log to try to understand it, you will need the dsym file generated with your app for that.
More answers in that post : [Symbolicate XCode4 crash reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248132/symbolicate-xcode4-crash-reports)