# Weird crash report

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, crash

My app is crashing with this printed out in console:

```
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown ReportCrash[6560] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process DixieMatTracker[6558]
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown ReportCrash[6560] <Error>: libMobileGestalt loadBasebandMobileEquipmentInfo: CommCenter error: 1:45
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown ReportCrash[6560] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.dixiemat.DixieMatTracker[0xf801]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown ReportCrash[6560] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copyInternationalMobileEquipmentIdentity: Could not get mobile equipment info dictionary
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown ReportCrash[6560] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DixieMatTracker_2011-07-03-173947_Ahmeds-iPod.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown com.apple.SpringBoard[28] <Notice>: CoreAnimation: timed out fence 500
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown SpringBoard[28] <Warning>: Application 'DixieMatTracker' exited abnormally with signal 5: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Jul  3 17:39:47 unknown DTPower[2832] <Warning>: Task info failed for task com.dixiemat.DixieMatTracker
```

I have absolutely no idea what this is, this is the first time I got something like this. Please help, thanks.

**UPDATE:** Here's the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: DDB4A051-A282-4152-ACE9-651161A9629C
CrashReporter Key:   9185dbd80ba3cc9fed14413529e4c277f99bca98
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         DixieMatTracker [6746]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/8E65FC0C-0654-43CA-A126-96C4A0870E11/DixieMatTracker.app/DixieMatTracker
Identifier:      DixieMatTracker
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-07-03 20:00:19.304 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x301f2c9a 0x301f0000 + 11418
1   CoreFoundation                  0x35c3deb4 0x35c38000 + 24244
2   Foundation                      0x335f81c4 0x335f7000 + 4548
3   UIKit                           0x329d9f08 0x329d6000 + 16136
4   GraphicsServices                0x30a35e70 0x30a31000 + 20080
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35cada90 0x35c38000 + 481936
6   CoreFoundation                  0x35caf838 0x35c38000 + 489528
7   CoreFoundation                  0x35cb0606 0x35c38000 + 493062
8   CoreFoundation                  0x35c40ebc 0x35c38000 + 36540
9   CoreFoundation                  0x35c40dc4 0x35c38000 + 36292
10  GraphicsServices                0x30a35418 0x30a31000 + 17432
11  GraphicsServices                0x30a354c4 0x30a31000 + 17604
12  UIKit                           0x32a04d62 0x329d6000 + 191842
13  UIKit                           0x32a02800 0x329d6000 + 182272
14  DixieMatTracker                 0x000c3484 0xc2000 + 5252
15  DixieMatTracker                 0x000c342c 0xc2000 + 5164

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31d00fbc 0x31cee000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31ec7032 0x31ec1000 + 24626
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x31ec803a 0x31ec1000 + 28730
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x31ec75ea 0x31ec1000 + 26090
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7a58a 0x35e46000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7abbc 0x35e46000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31cfdc00 0x31cee000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31cfd758 0x31cee000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35cae2b8 0x35c38000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35cb0562 0x35c38000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35c40ebc 0x35c38000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35c40dc4 0x35c38000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x35f1127e 0x35f0b000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7930a 0x35e46000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7abb4 0x35e46000 + 215988

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31cfdc00 0x31cee000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31cfd758 0x31cee000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35cae2b8 0x35c38000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35cb0562 0x35c38000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35c40ebc 0x35c38000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35c40dc4 0x35c38000 + 36292
6   Foundation                      0x336217f6 0x335f7000 + 174070
7   Foundation                      0x33614382 0x335f7000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x336865c6 0x335f7000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7930a 0x35e46000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7abb4 0x35e46000 + 215988

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31cffc60 0x31cee000 + 72800
1   CoreFoundation                  0x35cb38f2 0x35c38000 + 506098
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7930a 0x35e46000 + 209674
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7abb4 0x35e46000 + 215988

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 5:
0   ImageIO                         0x32e55b3a 0x32e23000 + 207674
1   ImageIO                         0x32e5507a 0x32e23000 + 204922
2   ImageIO                         0x32e57a9c 0x32e23000 + 215708
3   ImageIO                         0x32e54a8c 0x32e23000 + 203404
4   ImageIO                         0x32e48272 0x32e23000 + 152178
5   ImageIO                         0x32e48364 0x32e23000 + 152420
6   ImageIO                         0x32e3db3a 0x32e23000 + 109370
7   PhotoLibrary                    0x35300868 0x35238000 + 821352
8   PhotoLibrary                    0x3530090a 0x35238000 + 821514
9   PhotoLibrary                    0x352e8cd2 0x35238000 + 724178
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x31ecc8e0 0x31ec1000 + 47328
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x31ec7626 0x31ec1000 + 26150
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7a58a 0x35e46000 + 214410
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7abbc 0x35e46000 + 215996

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31d003ec 0x31cee000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7a6d8 0x35e46000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7abbc 0x35e46000 + 215996

Thread 7:
0   TextInput                       0x33795038 0x3377d000 + 98360
1   TextInput                       0x3378ad0c 0x3377d000 + 56588
2   TextInput                       0x337885b0 0x3377d000 + 46512
3   TextInput                       0x33789a6a 0x3377d000 + 51818
4   TextInput                       0x3378a1ba 0x3377d000 + 53690
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7930a 0x35e46000 + 209674
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35e7abb4 0x35e46000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x2081fb80    r1: 0x32cd05c0      r2: 0x40000000      r3: 0x301f2c89
    r4: 0x40000000    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x1f190400      r7: 0x2febf4b8
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x2febf458     r10: 0x1fca5bd0     r11: 0x32cc76a4
    ip: 0x3ef8779c    sp: 0x2febf4a0      lr: 0x35c3b1a1      pc: 0x301f2c9a
  cpsr: 0x20070030

Binary Images:
   0xc2000 -   0x146fff +DixieMatTracker armv7  <6333ab61669d356dbe9b2a8671645f2c> /var/mobile/Applications/8E65FC0C-0654-43CA-A126-96C4A0870E11/DixieMatTracker.app/DixieMatTracker
0x2fec1000 - 0x2fee6fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30193000 - 0x30198fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x301ea000 - 0x301edfff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x301f0000 - 0x302b4fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x302b8000 - 0x302bbfff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x302bc000 - 0x303c4fff  CoreData armv7  <9843a401dd1d322383e3e40021cc8b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x30426000 - 0x3042bfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3045a000 - 0x3048dfff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x304aa000 - 0x305bcfff  MediaPlayer armv7  <da848c0745a637af81d7edd962a09324> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x30664000 - 0x3069bfff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x306c6000 - 0x306effff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x307d8000 - 0x307dafff  Camera armv7  <fd4d53b318ab35ce9bb89db3879120f0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Camera.framework/Camera
0x307db000 - 0x30825fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3082a000 - 0x30847fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x30848000 - 0x3090efff  MusicLibrary armv7  <71a09022bd8b3b6a90a250199d190f10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x3093e000 - 0x30948fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30959000 - 0x30a02fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x30a2b000 - 0x30a30fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x30a31000 - 0x30a3dfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30a3e000 - 0x30a44fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x30a4b000 - 0x30a4cfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x30a56000 - 0x30b70fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30b71000 - 0x30b8afff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x30b8b000 - 0x30c3afff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30c46000 - 0x30c49fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x30c4a000 - 0x30c4ffff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x30c50000 - 0x30c59fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x30c5a000 - 0x30c9cfff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30df7000 - 0x30dfefff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30e04000 - 0x30e2ffff  IMFoundation armv7  <f1f21bedbf2e3ea38f692abef0005d76> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x30f40000 - 0x30f47fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x30f4c000 - 0x31039fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3103a000 - 0x3107dfff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31564000 - 0x31564fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x31631000 - 0x31635fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x31636000 - 0x3165afff  MediaControl armv7  <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x3179f000 - 0x317a8fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x317c8000 - 0x31914fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31915000 - 0x3195afff  IMAVCore armv7  <a4dbb6f1203e3f569080707b3a388573> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x3195b000 - 0x3195efff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x319ae000 - 0x31a32fff  AVFoundation armv7  <eeaf5f4f822436a5bd1655f536e69879> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31a66000 - 0x31ab4fff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x31b00000 - 0x31b01fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x31b1d000 - 0x31b7cfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31b7d000 - 0x31c9efff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31cb8000 - 0x31cedfff  ImageCapture armv7  <2c474beec10f3791ac8a1d37df04600f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x31cee000 - 0x31d05fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x31d50000 - 0x31d6ffff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x31de7000 - 0x31e35fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x31e36000 - 0x31e6afff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x31e77000 - 0x31eaffff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31ebe000 - 0x31ec0fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x31ec1000 - 0x31ecefff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x31ed8000 - 0x31ed9fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31eeb000 - 0x31ef1fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x31ef7000 - 0x31f37fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32037000 - 0x32039fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32062000 - 0x32064fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32065000 - 0x32069fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3207d000 - 0x3207dfff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x320bb000 - 0x323cefff  GeoServices armv7  <88616f3deada3bb495fc15e3ba58dc83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x3244a000 - 0x3244dfff  ArtworkCache armv7  <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x324d4000 - 0x324d5fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x324f8000 - 0x324f8fff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x327fc000 - 0x327fffff  MediaRemote armv7  <0804293b2774359189f3a67e2c81558d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x32800000 - 0x32833fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x3285e000 - 0x328b3fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x328d0000 - 0x329d4fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x329d6000 - 0x32d63fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32d65000 - 0x32d80fff  FTServices armv7  <e23c3572bf3a36a3a99364d18c484f1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x32d88000 - 0x32d8afff  SpringBoardUI armv7  <90ba5da3e3e337e0a83e2c2589d951a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
0x32e23000 - 0x32eb8fff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x32eb9000 - 0x32ecbfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x32ecc000 - 0x32efbfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x32efc000 - 0x32f3bfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x32f4c000 - 0x32f51fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x32f52000 - 0x32f8afff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x32f8c000 - 0x32fa2fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x32fbf000 - 0x32fc7fff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x32fc8000 - 0x330f4fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x330fc000 - 0x3310afff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3314f000 - 0x3315bfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3316d000 - 0x331b3fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x331b6000 - 0x331b6fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x331bc000 - 0x33262fff  Celestial armv7  <7fbd02fa664b33babaf0327c320d1491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x33267000 - 0x332adfff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x332c5000 - 0x335b2fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x335da000 - 0x335e1fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x335e2000 - 0x335effff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x335f0000 - 0x335f6fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x335f7000 - 0x33716fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3377d000 - 0x351cbfff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x35238000 - 0x35337fff  PhotoLibrary armv7  <c1e3cd36fb03398ca0c4482b073cc55e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x3533a000 - 0x3533afff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x35441000 - 0x35461fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x35514000 - 0x35583fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35584000 - 0x35635fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35638000 - 0x356d5fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x356d6000 - 0x356e1fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x357c9000 - 0x357cafff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x357cb000 - 0x357cdfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x357d4000 - 0x35890fff  MapKit armv7  <9a7a16643a573b18adecdb56fa879f93> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x35891000 - 0x35950fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3595e000 - 0x35960fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x359c4000 - 0x35a01fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x35a04000 - 0x35b58fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35b59000 - 0x35baafff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35c0b000 - 0x35c35fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <c525f00262b133848a3742b2c6ed0e87> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x35c38000 - 0x35d1dfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x35d23000 - 0x35d33fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x35d3d000 - 0x35d52fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x35d5c000 - 0x35d91fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35d95000 - 0x35ddefff  IMCore armv7  <9c1e280e1fa33fa784cad479b9cbd941> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x35de0000 - 0x35df3fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35df4000 - 0x35df6fff  MailServices armv7  <74ae0145ef713c6d91fd8f68885b0a61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x35e46000 - 0x35ec7fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35ee8000 - 0x35efafff  TelephonyUI armv7  <e2c34b9a391e3384875ac552dbca0ad4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x35efc000 - 0x35f05fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x35f06000 - 0x35f0afff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x35f0b000 - 0x36516fff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x365cf000 - 0x3660bfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x366ae000 - 0x366cefff  AppleAccount armv7  <4e0ac5cf93b338ab8c5f34ba3c5e2ee4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x366eb000 - 0x366f7fff  HomeSharing armv7  <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x366fe000 - 0x366fffff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
```

Comment: Did you ever find out anything here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) to get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Open up Organizer and look for the crash logs for your device to see the REAL crash log.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Updated my question with the crash log. thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately without more detail in the crash log we cannot make out way cause the application to crash.  Add the directory ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator to the spotlight ignore list, as per the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log  I wouldn't add DerivedData myself...