# Error while symbolicate crash logs

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have attached my iphone device and then i go to organizer and then click on device logs.I read that when i open device log it will automatically symbolicate that crash thread but this is not happen in xcode4. can anyone please tell me the process how to symbolicate crash report?

Comment: you should refer the below similar question. Hope its helps you.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log