# Application symbols not showing up while time profiling iPhone app in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I'm doing some time profiling XCode 4 but I can never seem to get the application symbols showin up in the call tree in Instruments.  I'm only getting system calls.

I thought this might be from doing something wrong like not generating debug symbols but after ensuring they were enabled the problem still seems to be persisting for me.  This has been working for me in XCode 3.x but I've never been able to get it to work in XCode 4.  Has anyone experienced this type of behaviour before or can perhaps tell me what I might be missing?

Comment: Some of the old workarounds to symbolicating crash reports can affect Instruments.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log

Comment: Thanks John.  That discussion had the answer I needed.  Using "mdimport ~/Library/Developer/" to have spotlight re-index that folder and restarting Instruments I'm now getting the call tree I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this problem is pretty much as outline in this post referred to by John in comments...

[Xcode 4 failure to symbolicate Crash Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log)

For me to get things to work I used...

```
mdimport ~/Library/Developer/
```

to have spotlight re-index the entire "Developer" folder in my user directory which is maybe a bit of overkill? Could've used `mdimport ~/Library/Developer/XCode` I suppose but I figure why not do one folder up.