# Symbolicate crash log

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, symbolicate, symbolicatecrash

I am using XCode 3.2.6. I made a build for my testers using "Build & Archive" method. I received some crash logs from my testers. I placed them on my desktop and dragged them to my organizer. But it doesn't symbolicate. I looked up online on how to symbolicate the crash logs and literally found more than a dozen different answers and responses.

I tried looking for symbolicatecrash on my computer and could not locate it anywhere. Is that the reason why my organizer is not symbolicating it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you kept the dSYM for that app? Without it you won't get the information. symbolicatecrash is no sperate tool anymore.

Comment: Yeah, I have saved the dSYM for that build.

Comment: Have you tried Xcode - Organizer - Devices - Library - Devices - Device Logs and there import that crash file?

Comment: Tried. No luck :( Why is it so hard to just symbolicate a crash log?!

Answer (score 0):

I've wrestled for this problem for quite a while... the solution that finally worked for me was (bizarrely) to add some folders to Spotlight's Privacy list, and try again. More info here: [Xcode 4 failure to symbolicate Crash Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log)

Comment: I tried it and still doesn't work. I have placed the symbolicatecrash along with the dYSM and my .app file in a separate folder on my desktop.