# issue symbolicating crash logs from other device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

My friend has sent me his crash log and I tried to symbolicate it by dragging it to my device logs window in XCode's 4 organizer. However this doesn't do anything.. why is this? I have tried doing build and archive on my app project. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to several reasons, ranging from issues with your archive to issues with your XCode and dev environment. There are plenty of posts and Q&As on the subject out there.

Try this to get you started;

- [The symbolicator helps those who helps themselves](http://www.goosoftware.co.uk/blog/the-symbolicator-helps-those-who-help-themselves/)

Also check out these questions;

- [Xcode 4 failure to symbolicate Crash Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log)
- [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports)

Comment: "Guide to symbolicating iphone crash logs" seems to be 404 now. A quick google search didn't bear any fruit. Do you have another link?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Adam. Afraid this post is a bit old, so can't remember the exact content in that article to suggest something else, but a couple of newer posts I found out on the web; (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707453/why-are-my-crash-reports-not-symbolicated) and (http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs) might help.