# Understanding iPhone Crash Log...Having No Luck

Tags: ios, crash-log

AppStore rejected app for crashing although I cannot replicate the issue on simulator or device.

Here is the crash log which I cannot symbolicate even after following detailed instructions
from here [How to symbolicate crash log Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855389/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-xcode-6)
Can anybody help decipher the crash log itself

```
Incident Identifier: 54A732D9-02FB-4B43-9784-84931F15A53D
CrashReporter Key:   09ad0b91dc85fc08d672efb5d6a9629b1e5cbf1c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             MyApp [1716]
Path:                
Identifier:          
Version:             1.06 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-20 12:42:20.20 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-10-20 12:42:12.12 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x185748f5c 0x19a31bf80 0x183c8434c 0x1000997a4 0x18acd980c 0x18acd9308 0x18acd9190 0x18a4a9040 0x19ab09770 0x19ab0ee20 0x185700258 0x1856fe0c0 0x18562cdc0 0x1905d4088 0x18ad06f44 0x10009dcfc 0x19ab3a8b8)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ac631e0 0x19ac48000 + 111072
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ad2cf0c 0x19ad28000 + 20236
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019abcab78 0x19ab68000 + 404344
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001999993f4 0x199998000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001999b5e98 0x199998000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a31c248 0x19a314000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001999b2f44 0x199998000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001999b2fd0 0x199998000 + 110544
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a31c1a4 0x19a314000 + 33188
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab09784 0x19ab08000 + 6020
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab0ee20 0x19ab08000 + 28192
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185700258 0x185624000 + 901720
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856fe0c0 0x185624000 + 893120
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018562cdc0 0x185624000 + 36288
14  GraphicsServices                0x00000001905d4088 0x1905c8000 + 49288
15  UIKit                           0x000000018ad06f44 0x18ac8c000 + 503620
16  MyApp                   0x000000010009dcfc 0x100090000 + 56572
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019ab3a8b8 0x19ab38000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ac6459c 0x19ac48000 + 116124
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab1ca04 0x19ab08000 + 84484
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab0b93c 0x19ab08000 + 14652

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ac63c0c 0x19ac48000 + 113676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ad29538 0x19ad28000 + 5432
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ad29028 0x19ad28000 + 4136

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ac63c0c 0x19ac48000 + 113676
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ad29538 0x19ad28000 + 5432
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ad29028 0x19ad28000 + 4136

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.coremedia.capturesource.notifications
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ac48d2c 0x19ac48000 + 3372
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000019ad25534 0x19ad20000 + 21812
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000019ac90920 0x19ac8c000 + 18720
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a335ae8 0x19a314000 + 137960
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018562cb6c 0x185624000 + 35692
5   Foundation                      0x00000001865a7c90 0x186594000 + 81040
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856ee6ac 0x185624000 + 829100
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856edecc 0x185624000 + 827084
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001856edc4c 0x185624000 + 826444
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185753434 0x185624000 + 1242164
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018562e834 0x185624000 + 43060
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018565125c 0x185624000 + 184924
12  CoreMedia                       0x0000000185f880dc 0x185f6c000 + 114908
13  CoreMedia                       0x0000000186038704 0x185f6c000 + 837380
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab097b0 0x19ab08000 + 6064
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab09770 0x19ab08000 + 6000
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab1575c 0x19ab08000 + 55132
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab0d274 0x19ab08000 + 21108
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab1762c 0x19ab08000 + 63020
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019ab1734c 0x19ab08000 + 62284
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ad29478 0x19ad28000 + 5240
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019ad29028 0x19ad28000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000070021   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000137018038  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000003fff
   x12: 0x0000000136d8c000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000170  x17: 0x000000019a336a74  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016e12f000
   x20: 0x0000000000000021  x21: 0x00000000800020ff  x22: 0x0000000000002907  x23: 0x00000001a14e0000
   x24: 0x0000000000010000  x25: 0x00000001a14ec000  x26: 0x0000000080000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016e12ef70   lr: 0x000000019ad29538
    sp: 0x000000016e12eef0   pc: 0x000000019ac63c0c cpsr: 0x40000000
```

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing to answer here; you have no info whatever about this crash. If you can't symbolicate, you are hosed. You should be thinking about why you can't symbolicate.

Comment: Trying to understand a unsymbolicated crash log is like trying to understand cave drawings. You can get a little info from them, but not enough to really point to something. It looks like your app is making a call to UIKit and it's crashing because of it. That's pretty much the whole extent of the info you've provided.

Comment: You don't have to try and understand it. Run the app in your device that crashes and send that crash log to your Xcode. Open organiser and open that crash in your Xcode.

Comment: And read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3536386/2053537

Comment: @matt When I try and Symbolicate I get a lot of info but "UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Myname/Desktop/CrashReport/MyApp.app/MyApp" may be causing an issue?? Any knowledge on this?

Comment: When you submitted your app to the app store, you archived it first. You kept the archive - didn't you? That is the archive you need in order to symbolicate, because it is the one with the symbols in it for this build.

Comment: This approach has always worked for me to symbolicate the crashlog: http://www.juliusparishy.com/articles/symbolicating-ios-8-crash-logs

Comment: Try running the app from Xcode on your device, but set the Build Settings -> Optimization Level -> Debug to "Fast". Often applications that do not crash in development but do in "release" fail due to a bug only detectable with optimization on. If you can replicate the crash the debugger will give you a hint of approximately where the crash occurred.