# App Crash on iPad after update to XCode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I updated XCode like MacOS suggested to XCode 8. I run my App on Simulator and it worked fine. But when i tried to run the App on my iPad the App crashed unexpected. 
I was looking for the problem but couldn't find any place because it still runs on simulator. But then installed the older XCode 7.3.1 again and the app runs again on my iPad.
Here is the CrashLog :

```
Incident Identifier: 3756AFDE-0D06-4401-BD20-4352991F773B
CrashReporter Key:   ebdd050a249780097b3342e8a223149b3afac815
Hardware Model:      iPad4,2
Process:             BLAA [1057]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/ECE0A2F1-B367-4AAD-8162-ED58E73C6C50/VISUS.app/VISUS
Identifier:          BLAA.server
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-10-11 10:15:24.24 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-10-11 10:15:20.20 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x180f3adb0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18059ff80 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   Foundation                      0x1818b4704 -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __failWithException:] + 132
3   Foundation                      0x1818b48bc -[NSCoder(Exceptions) __failWithExceptionName:errorCode:format:] + 440
4   Foundation                      0x1818833b8 _decodeObjectBinary + 2996
5   Foundation                      0x18188274c _decodeObject + 304
6   UIKit                           0x186567688 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1220
7   UIKit                           0x186409230 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 376
8   UIKit                           0x1861ce118 -[UIViewController loadView] + 176
9   UIKit                           0x1860908ec -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 144
10  UIKit                           0x1860a90d0 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 132
11  UIKit                           0x186243e5c -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1052
12  UIKit                           0x18614fe40 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
13  UIKit                           0x18614fb1c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
14  UIKit                           0x18614fa84 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
15  UIKit                           0x18608c1e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
16  QuartzCore                      0x183a1e994 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
17  QuartzCore                      0x183a195d0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
18  QuartzCore                      0x183a19490 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
19  QuartzCore                      0x183a18ac0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
20  QuartzCore                      0x183a18820 CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
21  QuartzCore                      0x183a11de4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
22  CoreFoundation                  0x180ef0728 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
23  CoreFoundation                  0x180eee4cc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
24  CoreFoundation                  0x180eee8fc __CFRunLoopRun + 928
25  CoreFoundation                  0x180e18c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
26  GraphicsServices                0x182700088 GSEventRunModal + 180
27  UIKit                           0x1860fa088 UIApplicationMain + 204
28  VISUS                           0x10004971c 0x100044000 + 22300
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x1809b68b8 start + 4


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
2.660349     CFNetwork                  0x000000018160e0a4 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
2.661763     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815d9d50 HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [12:8])
2.664646     CFNetwork                  0x000000018155d73c _CFNetworkIsConnectedToInternet returning 0, flagsValid: 1, flags: 0x0
2.665455     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c0220 TCP Conn 0x1275d8e80 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2.665455     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815bff18 TCP Conn 0x1275d8e80 complete. fd: -1, err: -65554
2.665700     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c1444 TCP Conn 0x1275d8e80 event 3. err: -65554
2.669860     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c151c TCP Conn 0x1275d8e80 started
2.672486     CFNetwork                  0x000000018160e0a4 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
2.672756     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815d9d50 HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [12:8])
2.674290     CFNetwork                  0x000000018155d73c _CFNetworkIsConnectedToInternet returning 0, flagsValid: 1, flags: 0x0
2.675165     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c0220 TCP Conn 0x1275ce3d0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2.675165     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815bff18 TCP Conn 0x1275ce3d0 complete. fd: -1, err: -65554
2.676078     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c1444 TCP Conn 0x1275ce3d0 event 3. err: -65554
2.679100     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c151c TCP Conn 0x1275ce3d0 started
2.682027     CFNetwork                  0x000000018160e0a4 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
2.682605     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815d9d50 HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [12:8])
2.685203     CFNetwork                  0x000000018155d73c _CFNetworkIsConnectedToInternet returning 0, flagsValid: 1, flags: 0x0
2.686100     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c0220 TCP Conn 0x1276abba0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2.686100     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815bff18 TCP Conn 0x1276abba0 complete. fd: -1, err: -65554
2.688915     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c1444 TCP Conn 0x1276abba0 event 3. err: -65554
2.691734     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c151c TCP Conn 0x1276abba0 started
2.693133     CFNetwork                  0x000000018160e0a4 NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1009
2.693526     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815d9d50 HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [12:8])
2.698032     CFNetwork                  0x000000018155d73c _CFNetworkIsConnectedToInternet returning 0, flagsValid: 1, flags: 0x0
2.698793     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c0220 TCP Conn 0x1276a7fb0 Failed : error 0:-65554 [-65554]
2.698793     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815bff18 TCP Conn 0x1276a7fb0 complete. fd: -1, err: -65554
2.699551     CFNetwork                  0x00000001815c1444 TCP Conn 0x1276a7fb0 event 3. err: -65554



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad411c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180ba0ef8 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000180a45dac abort + 140
3   VISUS                           0x000000010016c1b8 0x100044000 + 1212856
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180f3b138 __handleUncaughtException + 652
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001805a023c _objc_terminate() + 112
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180592f44 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000180592b10 __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001805a0120 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180e18cf8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000182700088 GSEventRunModal + 180
11  UIKit                           0x00000001860fa088 UIApplicationMain + 204
12  VISUS                           0x000000010004971c 0x100044000 + 22300
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001809b68b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad54d8 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001809987d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180987648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ab8fd8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ab8e54 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ef0c60 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180eee964 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180e18c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181599c68 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 412
6   Foundation                      0x000000018190fe4c __NSThread__start__ + 1000
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9fb28 _pthread_body + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9fa8c _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d028 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180ad4b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180b9d020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0xffffffffffffffff
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000003c57  x11: 0x00000001a14e96d9
   x12: 0x00000001a14e96d9  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x000000008000001f  x15: 0x0000000080000023
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001001b8270  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019f013000  x21: 0x0000000127709120  x22: 0x00000001275f7ce0  x23: 0x000000019f01f150
   x24: 0x000000019f023000  x25: 0x96006092194ae3d3  x26: 0x0000000186abe5b0  x27: 0x0000000181171ba5
   x28: 0x000000019e0f8588  fp: 0x000000016fdbb830   lr: 0x0000000180ba0ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fdbb810   pc: 0x0000000180ad411c cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100044000 - 0x1001b7fff VISUS arm64  <fc9818f7896039468eae4a57c3cf30eb> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/ECE0A2F1-B367-4AAD-8162-ED58E73C6C50/VISUS.app/VISUS
0x120048000 - 0x120077fff dyld arm64  <488b8b4696fb312db76da956e6f5aef5> /usr/lib/dyld
0x180520000 - 0x180521fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <77c873c418a6317f821f7b706d5b7dc6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x180524000 - 0x180576fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <9ec0d9dcf728349582c26a7da72f0364> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x180578000 - 0x180597fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <aaa40b7f52513cf79c6f814b133556a7> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x180598000 - 0x180904fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <939f392022903f2da2858e676e4191ef> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x180908000 - 0x18090cfff libcache.dylib arm64  <43424f4c7252330ca92c1a865da896e1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x180910000 - 0x18091bfff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <e47d758d207e32c8ab546b59785d2ab8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x18091c000 - 0x18091ffff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <b77c451c7ffb356fb3c8368cac95d8f3> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x180920000 - 0x180927fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <1c1678aa36073b42b4406c6dbb06e9f0> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x180928000 - 0x180983fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <b42ff635d1303d45bafe057e5a1e6243> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x180984000 - 0x1809b2fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <65568801b7463adeb6e20dc25d14d801> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1809b4000 - 0x1809b6fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <e1f151766d6e3755a1a59f62d9a3d9f9> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1809b8000 - 0x1809b8fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <fbb5f1442c3039188da689963efde4d8> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1809bc000 - 0x1809c0fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <1f37b179ad26307192b3b763ba5f816a> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1809c4000 - 0x1809c5fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <267c6cbaf2193309bd8a191fad38cc79> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1809c8000 - 0x1809defff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <fffe50d37b1c3f92af6f4a68a6d60068> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1809e0000 - 0x1809e1fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <8bbf799e57f93ed1be24cf2ce6c221a3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1809e4000 - 0x180a63fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <a05dd3ed96153b1bb2da1954a08d4d23> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x180a64000 - 0x180a67fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <c5ce1ced5659354ab63871b42d04a7cd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x180a68000 - 0x180a6bfff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <504648cfa43d3668b9678b74e33697f2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x180a6c000 - 0x180a6dfff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <8f94549c633036aa99efb0f067031a05> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x180a70000 - 0x180a86fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <498e424eb31f3d5cb49523cec07f339d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x180a88000 - 0x180a90fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <096026a14628397ea96580ce7704f39e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x180a94000 - 0x180ab6fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <932df5ba705a3b6d948c5dcff196ea6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x180ab8000 - 0x180ad9fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <29df8d8d12d034ffa906bb02f04610f4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x180adc000 - 0x180af8fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <a97bf91d4a233dbc94bef06734a2eac0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x180afc000 - 0x180b15fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <a8af95191b283ca9aa7f9cf80c459bf5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x180b18000 - 0x180b7bfff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <a8e4200aecc73e56a8458a0e9cb4a6f0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x180b7c000 - 0x180b85fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <d1a7579c71943631845c2908d69bfbc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x180b88000 - 0x180b92fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <da8d7d155da230d287a67c46e9b3ccbc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x180b94000 - 0x180b99fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <4386956061113d7a9e415e543b1243bc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x180b9c000 - 0x180ba4fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <7965d331db2c3bd2b8cbc1bc78babca2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x180ba8000 - 0x180baafff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <f82362117e823f0fbcbf9922ca025f26> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x180bac000 - 0x180bbcfff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <fe1b1e8d0b3633c58d415c6fe8594903> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x180bc0000 - 0x180bc5fff libunwind.dylib arm64  <b0067e5ea3ca3b28abc5cb7d50390363> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x180bc8000 - 0x180bc8fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <630bf4c89edf3935b7afe56abdb5caad> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x180bcc000 - 0x180bf1fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <fc63a0a505523f7fac2c4ea9d9662ba1> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x180bf4000 - 0x180df9fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <9416014bb51e35aebdb2a9f572a2c5f8> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x180dfc000 - 0x180e0dfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <8fcb56adfdc13e9593582266b1e4ac18> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x180e10000 - 0x181190fff CoreFoundation arm64  <182fd72b7fdf330b8dbf70db93af6b63> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x181194000 - 0x1811a4fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <d045301bcacc37d785d754d5c978d979> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x1811a8000 - 0x1811a8fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <c4ee08bffdfc3ce0990c1fbeb858f9dc> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1811ac000 - 0x18121dfff IOKit arm64  <0864d9c20424332d8979a4f548848c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x181220000 - 0x181240fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <9cc485a12c323768a6b6e88d973bd44e> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x181244000 - 0x18132efff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <be446a86b5fa3620beeeb3a56a320e7b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x181330000 - 0x1813a2fff Security arm64  <85e9578e7bc732ca9cced737b84163bb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1813a4000 - 0x1813fdfff SystemConfiguration arm64  <92717250c7393c44878d137773604d46> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x181400000 - 0x1814e8fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <c703a175f1c43ed28d81b839ba961183> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1814ec000 - 0x181780fff CFNetwork arm64  <aaa7ff247b7b3357aa90f6a4dddf0697> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x181784000 - 0x181791fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <8ebfd413e3fd3889b546857fcf554b6f> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x181794000 - 0x1817adfff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <68bb861dc8bd3547b5ace073ed504b14> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x1817b0000 - 0x1817cafff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <1a2c1f709f213faf81fd2223b719c899> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1817cc000 - 0x1817f6fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <bf6ae1a9c965363ba9f10ff0ca32ee7c> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1817f8000 - 0x181816fff libextension.dylib arm64  <8a88fb35fee03a36ae138e676b9a0e9f> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x181818000 - 0x181819fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <cdb184e30c3c303694a96b3150520673> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x18181c000 - 0x181a8afff Foundation arm64  <7cf4edf781cb30438b812ded8716cd95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x181a8c000 - 0x181b37fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <097b7e769a3439ad8fdb3abb0edc9daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x181b38000 - 0x181e9dfff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <566419f65c9338599694a04da8e20fbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x181ea0000 - 0x182105fff vImage arm64  <789df1b35e183397803583a25feff3c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x182108000 - 0x18212afff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <3c655ae6f62035bbba069387c490efbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x18212c000 - 0x18213ffff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <94d099e954d638e39ef1773639ef61af> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x182140000 - 0x18214ffff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <80ca4fb770613c76b2449daf05c6dc25> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x182150000 - 0x1821bcfff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <f4e8d68f55af3511a28a616737dcc354> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1821c0000 - 0x1821c0fff vecLib arm64  <546ad53c3a4a36709fdf6e50b76b2ec9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1821c4000 - 0x1821c4fff Accelerate arm64  <a1953e95570a3de6a923a812ffbd90ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1821c8000 - 0x1826f3fff CoreGraphics arm64  <63001c4acb4135428df4b62f2f698e0f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x1826f4000 - 0x182708fff GraphicsServices arm64  <d8509ae0233539218bf97db29a7d31c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18270c000 - 0x182754fff AppSupport arm64  <1469530c1aa03d2486d678bed8482764> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x182758000 - 0x18282bfff MobileCoreServices arm64  <2096d560a53b3fd28ff0a7f46e3ba060> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18282c000 - 0x18287bfff BaseBoard arm64  <b6f2014b564430538f5252776acfa530> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18287c000 - 0x182887fff AssertionServices arm64  <48c978bd14553765b4a7f1cee1b14c83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x182888000 - 0x1828acfff BackBoardServices arm64  <207836d8c1833eeab468f622f4d0f366> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x1828b0000 - 0x1828b3fff MobileSystemServices arm64  <6d85ae92680935bbb51db96c7a021118> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x1828b4000 - 0x1828e9fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <b1a46eb324d23a51813b565ae7f04b88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1828ec000 - 0x1828f6fff UserNotificationServices arm64  <74d3e76dff833048b39ae8e0ceb44140> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
0x1828f8000 - 0x182924fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <6535787e172939d0b8abfe852a185b3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x182928000 - 0x182939fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <169edc8949693d349807056d1e316f2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18293c000 - 0x182942fff IOSurface arm64  <d62fd4ed209e32f98d5dbc34f9484ef4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x182944000 - 0x182950fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <36e1e9187c193410a5f7cf46e3dc7afe> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x182954000 - 0x182966fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <8e45addb6a1f379d98c9164764948fc2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x182968000 - 0x18296afff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <65789d64b5f937e987c6f27125a38100> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18296c000 - 0x1829adfff AppleJPEG arm64  <24fc6e2cd59a318e9f59da6383bfd90d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x1829b0000 - 0x182cd2fff ImageIO arm64  <8b10562bfdd23addb249367deb92aefd> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x182cd4000 - 0x182cd8fff TCC arm64  <09fcccda721f35c3936e68acf3d216a4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x182cdc000 - 0x182ce1fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <51bcd4b61f3739eb85fdcc4a037e3696> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x182ce4000 - 0x182cf1fff PowerLog arm64  <a50ba8508d733823be55425db249606c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x182cf4000 - 0x182d56fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <59e0bc898f27370d8e4961910f891b3b> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x182d58000 - 0x182d6afff CommonUtilities arm64  <194ea4f46bf537029d10e4ce8b28ca5f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x182d6c000 - 0x182d83fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <ac77f3a3cad832a7b748c30e013bbc0b> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x182d84000 - 0x182fcefff CoreData arm64  <aa00d2e704e333e199f8e34b3c661b12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x182fd0000 - 0x182fd4fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <69b5ba7317d532b898c3ffb5574bb883> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x182fd8000 - 0x182fdcfff IOAccelerator arm64  <d92ad93b196b38a6b054b1cc3fbd1f1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x182fe0000 - 0x182fe1fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <ed32d5e2c1e630b18097aa7890c92171> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x182fe4000 - 0x182fe7fff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <abe2067778503127a31c42352d2e43ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x182fe8000 - 0x18302efff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <e67acd0811bf318dadb48a49b97bee7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x183030000 - 0x18303afff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <fdc295986ea03203bbfc904ffc4cca6b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x18303c000 - 0x183043fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <f82bfbe1dc083eabb7ff1a8d9980fe47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x183044000 - 0x183044fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <bdc8f33a1b453c8f827726c7f46640dc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x183048000 - 0x18308efff Metal arm64  <95ce1f8a4d483d11aa49533e2ae2a568> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x183090000 - 0x18309afff OpenGLES arm64  <7c7a0c5191f53f518e994638139ca1df> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x18309c000 - 0x1830befff CoreVideo arm64  <31ef8b764af3301ea5e7267fcae838cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x1830c0000 - 0x1830c2fff OAuth arm64  <0f1ae5abcad13b4b948193a2405c61b4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x1830c4000 - 0x1830fbfff Accounts arm64  <1cf893c2c3c03137acb576d5a7fc2cee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1830fc000 - 0x1831eefff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <1c378c57054a32a6b2eed4e3cbb3a2b7> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x1831f0000 - 0x1832a9fff CoreAudio arm64  <25687ef4b3c4389f828006882b280db4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1832ac000 - 0x1832affff UserFS arm64  <693602c29c64370aab1a77544ddc7e5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x1832b0000 - 0x18339efff CoreMedia arm64  <51c728b4974936448426dccd30e3fc5a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x1833a0000 - 0x1833a8fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <056df1f0f2893ad08b9c7fbed9271c6f> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x1833ac000 - 0x18341efff CoreTelephony arm64  <d48572ad7be13a99b7a783c12c6657f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x183420000 - 0x183500fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <7ab9c32919d731969bc2a75b3f03aa17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x183504000 - 0x183586fff VideoToolbox arm64  <0902a89a960935c08b3715cadedc2a50> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x183588000 - 0x183588fff FontServices arm64  <39a3005cf101328f94f3a412cfa04fae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18358c000 - 0x1836affff CoreText arm64  <5d80f981ab953f73b08881908a610117> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x1836b0000 - 0x1836c1fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <4d1a9d53f37b3b448cbc62ede839532f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
```

can anybody explain me what happend ??

Comment: comment out all of method you called in viewdidload or apploading time. Load a blank screen. Then it could be tell that the crash is relate to system.

Comment: Also check it . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536276/how-to-diagnose-exc-crash

Comment: Does it point to any lines of code that you have? or is this just an arbitrary crash via `SIGABRT `?

Comment: unfortunately not, it just crashes. The strange part is that the app runs again with XCode 7.3 . I haven't had time yet to check out what Jamshed Alam wrote. But i will answer this post after I have figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your iPad allows permissions that may have 
Been initiated, unlike iPhone.  I am so done 
With the pad I think I will burn it.  Load new 
iOS and run SOPHOS TRACE MODULE,  my 
Feeling is the auto access of many apps available 
Is a bit more secure than the old iOS. Failure to connect by a few previous "wide open doors "
Will halt the new iOS.  Remove all of your suspicious permissions from apps that have no 
Valid use for access to your personal data. Reload the iOS and give it a try....TP7