# iPAD App Quits on Launch with crash log EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have developed an application and successfully uploaded onto the Appstore.
Now I have upgraded my app and submitted the same to the AppStore, apple rejected my application saying that application is getting crashed after splash screen.

When I tested the application I have not got the crash not even a single time so i have submitted the app with some try catch blocks and fixed one issue with low wi-fi conditions.

But again apple rejected the app saying the same reason application is crashing after splash screen. Crash log says main thread is killed with EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT).

Apple is getting this crash 100% reproducible but for me not even once.

could anyone please help/suggest me to understand what the exact problem.

Below is the crash log shared by apple.

Thanks in advance...

```
Incident Identifier: 462DA5F9-403E-425F-AD94-A298300163EE
CrashReporter Key:   25bc4ee040c53d33c4bc541509cc502e98db0401
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:         MobileStyle [31055]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/D6082808-BE54-4DC1-A24E-13B51F9A7496/MobileStyle.app/MobileStyle
Identifier:      MobileStyle
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-09-15 13:50:38.931 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3596ba1c 0x3595a000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5d3b4 0x31a2a000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a55bf8 0x31a2a000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31ea7a64 0x31e63000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32e3406c 0x32e2e000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31ea5e36 0x31e63000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31ea5e8a 0x31e63000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x31ea5f5a 0x31e63000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32e32c84 0x32e2e000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3158a3c6 0x314ec000 + 648134
10  Foundation                      0x330d3ed4 0x3306c000 + 425684
11  Foundation                      0x3308c9c4 0x3306c000 + 133572
12  Foundation                      0x3308c210 0x3306c000 + 131600
13  UIKit                           0x35eb187c 0x35d4c000 + 1464444
14  Foundation                      0x3306e428 0x3306c000 + 9256
15  UIKit                           0x35f568d8 0x35d4c000 + 2140376
16  CoreFoundation                  0x31522d74 0x314ec000 + 224628
17  CoreFoundation                  0x31522996 0x314ec000 + 223638
18  UIKit                           0x35f55840 0x35d4c000 + 2136128
19  UIKit                           0x35f56e02 0x35d4c000 + 2141698
20  UIKit                           0x35ed05e2 0x35d4c000 + 1590754
21  UIKit                           0x35e9df9e 0x35d4c000 + 1384350
22  UIKit                           0x35d82eb8 0x35d4c000 + 224952
23  MobileStyle                     0x00034dca 0x1000 + 212426
24  MobileStyle                     0x0003531c 0x1000 + 213788
25  MobileStyle                     0x000358b8 0x1000 + 215224
26  UIKit                           0x35d82f08 0x35d4c000 + 225032
27  UIKit                           0x35d915e8 0x35d4c000 + 284136
28  UIKit                           0x35d91458 0x35d4c000 + 283736
29  UIKit                           0x35d91356 0x35d4c000 + 283478
30  UIKit                           0x35d90e2e 0x35d4c000 + 282158
31  UIKit                           0x35d90c3c 0x35d4c000 + 281660
32  UIKit                           0x35d90b80 0x35d4c000 + 281472
33  UIKit                           0x35d90b1c 0x35d4c000 + 281372
34  UIKit                           0x35d515f4 0x35d4c000 + 22004
35  CoreFoundation                  0x314f7efc 0x314ec000 + 48892
36  QuartzCore                      0x32f90bae 0x32f8e000 + 11182
37  QuartzCore                      0x32f90966 0x32f8e000 + 10598
38  QuartzCore                      0x32f908a0 0x32f8e000 + 10400
39  UIKit                           0x35d515d0 0x35d4c000 + 21968
40  UIKit                           0x35df976e 0x35d4c000 + 710510
41  UIKit                           0x35df8bba 0x35d4c000 + 707514
42  UIKit                           0x35dfc670 0x35d4c000 + 722544
43  UIKit                           0x35d908e4 0x35d4c000 + 280804
44  UIKit                           0x35df7a08 0x35d4c000 + 702984
45  UIKit                           0x35df66f0 0x35d4c000 + 698096
46  UIKit                           0x35df5cd0 0x35d4c000 + 695504
47  MobileStyle                     0x00033850 0x1000 + 206928
48  UIKit                           0x35d8181a 0x35d4c000 + 219162
49  UIKit                           0x35d7bb5e 0x35d4c000 + 195422
50  UIKit                           0x35d507d0 0x35d4c000 + 18384
51  UIKit                           0x35d5020e 0x35d4c000 + 16910
52  MobileStyle                     0x000b5780 0x1000 + 739200
53  UIKit                           0x35d4fc4c 0x35d4c000 + 15436
54  GraphicsServices                0x32057e70 0x32053000 + 20080
55  CoreFoundation                  0x31561a90 0x314ec000 + 481936
56  CoreFoundation                  0x31563838 0x314ec000 + 489528
57  CoreFoundation                  0x31564606 0x314ec000 + 493062
58  CoreFoundation                  0x314f4ebc 0x314ec000 + 36540
59  CoreFoundation                  0x314f4dc4 0x314ec000 + 36292
60  UIKit                           0x35d7ad42 0x35d4c000 + 191810
61  UIKit                           0x35d78800 0x35d4c000 + 182272
62  MobileStyle                     0x00002922 0x1000 + 6434
63  MobileStyle                     0x00002824 0x1000 + 6180

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3596c3ec 0x3595a000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5e6d8 0x31a2a000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5ebbc 0x31a2a000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3596cfbc 0x3595a000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x314ceed4 0x314ce000 + 3796
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x314cff3a 0x314ce000 + 7994
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x314cf4ec 0x314ce000 + 5356
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5e58a 0x31a2a000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5ebbc 0x31a2a000 + 215996

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3596c3ec 0x3595a000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5e6d8 0x31a2a000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5ebbc 0x31a2a000 + 215996

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35969c00 0x3595a000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35969758 0x3595a000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x315622b8 0x314ec000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31564562 0x314ec000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x314f4ebc 0x314ec000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x314f4dc4 0x314ec000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x322fc27e 0x322f6000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5d30a 0x31a2a000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5ebb4 0x31a2a000 + 215988

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3596c3ec 0x3595a000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5e6d8 0x31a2a000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31a5ebbc 0x31a2a000 + 215996

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3eba948c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x005a3bec      r7: 0x2fdfc2bc
    r8: 0x005a2590    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0039fb30     r11: 0x0039fb30
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfc2b0      lr: 0x31a5d3bb      pc: 0x3596ba1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010
```

Comment: Use the symbolication tool of Xcode to symbolicate the crash log, this will help you more than our guesses.

Comment: @chaitanya: You need to symbolicate this crash log. As I suppose no one will be able to guess what the error is from this memory addresses. We need to see the methods and objects and only then we can help you out.

Comment: thank you JustSid, Parth Bhatt. I did the symbolication of crash log. It is showing a line in my code which is accessing my viewcontrollers view. By mistake i added this line as objViewcontroller.view; [not assigning any thing and not retrieving anything]. will this cause any problem? my doubt is I have not got any crash with this code but apple is getting 100%. Our client also tested the app and didnt get the crash.

Comment: @chaitanya: Please check out the links I provided in my answer. They may help you to resymbolicate your crash log as well as solve your crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this link:

This might help you

[How to read crash log? How to find why the app crashes in system library? What means EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322198/how-to-read-crash-log-how-to-find-why-the-app-crashes-in-system-library-what-me)

This link explains the basic causes of the EXC_CRASH(SIGABRT) crashes and also it explains that you need a dSym files to symbolicate your crash log.

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

Also this links are very helpful. Please check them out:

[Xcode 4 failure to symbolicate Crash Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log)

[How to diagnose EXC_CRASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536276/how-to-diagnose-exc-crash)