# iPhone app with Spotify crashes after resigning .ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

When I try to resign .iPA file with different key and mobile provisioning profile my App crashes due to Spotify.

Is that because of "appkey.c" file or is there any relation between Spotify credentials and Apple provisioning profiles and keys which causes the app to crash?

If yes, what is the workaround to resolve this crash and to make my app work after resigning .ipa file?

Here are the crashlogs for keychain.

```
Feb 12 14:17:51 iPhone securityd[87] <Error>:  securityd_xpc_dictionary_handler MyApp[7338] copy_matching The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -34018 - client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements)
Feb 12 14:17:51 iPhone MyApp[7338] <Warning>: *** Assertion failure in NSString* base::deviceIdFromKeychain()(), /Users/spotify-buildagent/buildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/base/_apple/_ios/os_ios.mm:287
Feb 12 14:17:51 iPhone MyApp[7338] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Keychain error when fetching device ID, nonrecoverable'
```

Crash log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

set your user header search paths for release to include: `"$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include"`
for more refer [this Link :)](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/issues/49)

and also check out this link

[How to read crash log? How to find why the app crashes in system library? What means EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322198/how-to-read-crash-log-how-to-find-why-the-app-crashes-in-system-library-what-m)

This link explains the basic causes of the EXC_CRASH(SIGABRT) crashes and also it explains that you need a dSym files to symbolicate your crash log.

Hope this helps you.

Also this links are very helpful. Please check them out:

[Xcode 4 failure to symbolicate Crash Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458573/xcode-4-failure-to-symbolicate-crash-log)

[How to diagnose EXC_CRASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536276/how-to-diagnose-exc-crash)

Comment: Thanks for response ,the path you mention is already there for release.